# Deactivate a pipenv environment

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv, virtual-environment

How can I deactivate my pipenv environment?

With other tools I've been able to do something like `source deactivate`, but that has no affect here.

Create an environment:

```
pipenv --three
```

Activate the environment:

```
source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate
```

But how to deactivate?

Comment: Just a tip, when using pipenv as your package and environment manager, the tool already provides an easier command to activate the virtual environment, which is `pipenv shell` as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/basics/#example-pipenv-workflow), so no `source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate` required.

Comment: Type `exit` and you'll be in your bash.

Comment: The [current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49944909) is actually incorrect and even messes things up, as explained [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51075851). Could you please accept one of the correct answers?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**UPDATE**: See other answers below. As it has been explained, this works for `virtualenv`, but `pipenv` works differently.

Just type `deactivate` on the command line. See the guide [here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/)

Comment: The command deactivate would work for virtualenv but the tool used here is pipenv which works differently and the deactivate command will not work. One has to type exit in shell to close the virtual environment spawned by pipenv command. The answer is misleading

Comment: Link to guide is no longer correct

Answer (score 97):

To elaborate on Williams' answer a bit more, the [expected workflow](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/basics/#example-pipenv-workflow) is to enter the virtualenv using `pipenv shell`.  When you activate the virtualenv that way, the console output now indicates to use `exit`:

> Spawning environment shell (/bin/zsh). Use 'exit' to leave.

Trying to exit the virtualenv with `deactivate` will leave pipenv in a confused state because you will still be in that spawned shell instance but not in an activated virtualenv.

Comment: It would be possible to use `deactivate` to escape the venv if you use something like `source $(pipenv --venv)/bin/activate` to enter it.

Comment: thank you its helping me, clearly way, cause deactivate just work on virtualenv

Comment: "Expected workflow" link doesn't work

Answer (score 61):

Using the shell command `exit`  also works.

This worked for me when using `deactivate` still left me with the error:

```sh
Shell for UNKNOWN_VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT already activated.
No action taken to avoid nested environments.
```

After using `exit` I could successfully switch `pipenv` instances. This could well be a bug and I should probably report it.

Comment: From my understanding after reading through the issues on GitHub around this topic it isn't a bug. This (https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/84) particular ticket helped enlighten me... in summary, you can open a new shell and proceed as usual, or type `exit` and proceed as usual.

Answer (score 18):

Just type `exit`, and it will take you out of your shell.

And if you use `deactivate`, you will probably get the below error when you try to enter the shell again.

```
Shell for UNKNOWN_VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT already activated.
    No action taken to avoid nested environments.
```

So, it is prefer to use "exit" for quick access.

Comment: Quick note, if you have this error you can simply type 'exit' in the affected directory and it should successfully deactivate the pipenv shell.

Answer (score 12):

Deactivate from pipenv virtual environment, you can simply run the following command.

```
deactivate
```

Answer (score 7):

Please check this topic for answer from [contributor](https://github.com/kfirbreger) perspective:

https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/84#issuecomment-275056943

Spoiler :

> pipenv starts a new shell session with the virtualenv pathing instead of changing the pathing in the current shell session. That is why deactivate does not work. you need to exit the shell session. the exit command or CTRL-d will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First "deactivate" and then "exit" you will get out of the virtual env. As of now this worked for me.

Comment: The command `exit` already does the entire job, since `pipenv shell` spawns a new shell process as stated in the end of [this documentation block](https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/basics/#example-pipenv-workflow), no need to `deactivate` first.

Comment: It looks like @dandev486 's link is dead and the [new page](https://docs.pipenv.org/basics/#about-shell-configuration) does not really talk about how to exit. The [old docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20190717063720/https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/basics/#example-pipenv-workflow), FWIW, said "This will spawn a new shell subprocess, which can be deactivated by using exit.". Personally I think `exit` is still probably the right way to leave an env.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `pipenv shell` to activate virtual environment, and `exit` or `deactivate` doesn't work. Right click and kill terminal. That works for me

Comment: Killing the terminal may not be an option in general settings. Pipenv is a wrapper for managing environmental variables. Ending the session  with 'exit' should be enough.