# 'Exit' command in VS Code Terminal and pipenv

Tags: visual-studio-code, command, exit, pipenv

While in the VS Code Terminal, the 'exit' command or 'ctrl + d' combination closes the terminal directly, whereas I just want to deactive pipenv, is there a way to do this?

Comment: The only way to exit `pipenv` is to make a new Terminal (from the top bar menu) and then delete the old terminal.

Answer (score 7):

The following command helped me quit pipenv shell in vscode:

`deactivate`

Comment: Can you please add a bit more explanation. What does deactivate do? Any docs or links that I can reference? [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both `deactivate` and `exit`, but none of them works for me.

Environment and interpreters are easily changed with `shift+cmd+P`. Please, refer to [VS code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `pipenv shell` to enter virtualenv, use `exit` command to quit the virtualenv.

Please do not use `deactivate`, because it will behaved differently [explained by [ButtaKnife]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51075851/10857240)